# java getFileType on mac OSX not showing result

Tags: java, macos, file-io

i am creating a swing file manager that shows files and folders. i also need to show the **file type** of every file.

on windows i use

```
 JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
 File file = new File("myfilepath");

 String fileTypeName = chooser.getTypeDescription(file);
```

it shows the description of file type. For example if it is a txt file then it shows **"Text File"**.

But on mac osx it shows **"Generic File"** for all file types..

Comment: See if the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) achieves better.  It uses the `FileSystemView`.  Actually it was specifically [`getSystemTypeDescription(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getSystemTypeDescription%28java.io.File%29) that I was thinking of, which I apparently neglected to add to the table.  Very silly of me. :P

Comment: 'FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemTypeDescription(file);' this is not working on OSX

Comment: Does 'not working' mean `Generic File` is returned, a `NoSuchMethodError`, a `TooManyKittensForOneBowlOfMilkError`..?